# Python Selenium/PhantomJS Redirect

Tags: python, selenium, redirect, phantomjs

I have some troubles to use selenium/PhantomJS with python, in order to retrieve web page with redirect.

For example, if I try to read a linkedin page without being authenticated, I receive an html page with a javascript doing a window.location.
The selenium driver based on phantomJS does not follow this redirection and give me the "javascript page", instead of the redirected page.

```
> from selenium import webdriver
> d = webdriver.PhantomJS()
> d.get("https://www.linkedin.com/in/XXXX/")
> print(d.page_source)
[...]
window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/authwall?trk=" + trk + "&trkInfo=" + trkInfo +
[...]
```

However if I use the Firefox driver, the redirection is taken and it works like a charm.
Do you know how can I have the same behavior with PhantomJS ?

Comment: You are probably facing a defence mechanisme since you are violating the website [policy](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/56347/prohibition-of-scraping-software?lang=en). PhantomJS injects some variables in the page that are easy to detect. Firefox uses a sandbox, so all the injected code is not visible by the page. It makes it harder to detect an automated session.

Comment: if this is the case, could you try setting user-agent string, it might help.

Comment: Changing the user-agent string does not change the problem. Maybe there is a defense mechanism, but it does not explain why the javascript page sent is not interpreted by PhantomJS. The javascript sent seems correct, and should lead to a redirection.

Comment: Ok I have an idea of the problem: This javascript is probably sent with an HTTP code 999. So phantomJS does not interpret it. It's a supposition.